Clarification on BNL2 visa
I am an Indian passport holder with a valid UK visitor visa. I’m planning to fly to and from the UK via Munich by Lufthansa (3hrs layover). I have a valid multiple entry Schengen C type visa  (valid for 1 year, duration of stay 90 days) issued by Belgium with the remarks ‘BNL2' and 'TRANSIT’ and a valid USA C1D visa. My organisation instructed me to get the Belgium visa as I had to fly to Athens via Brussels to join a ship earlier. Do I need a separate Germany transit visa to fly from India to the UK (for tourism purpose) via Munich or will the already existing BNL2 visa suffice ?

BNL2 means visa issued ex officio, see related question. For completeness, is your proposed itinerary connecting flights (one PNR), or self-transfer?

Thank you. The connecting flight is in one PNR itself.

Your existing visa should suffice - you do not need a separate transit via for Germany.
